# jQuery .html() is not updating after Resetting the Form

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a custom validate On [this Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/52VtD/1240/)

```
  if (proceed) {
        file_name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
        file_area = $('#selArea').val();
        file_type = $('#selType').val();
        $('#fname').html(file_name.replace(/\s+/g, "_"));
        $('#sarea').html(file_area);
        $('#stype').html(file_type);
        $("#myform")[0].reset();
   }
```

the Problem is after validating the form .html() keeps older value for even next submission. at

```
   $('#fname').html(file_name.replace(/\s+/g, "_"));
   $('#sarea').html(file_area);
   $('#stype').html(file_type);
```

Can you please let me know why this is happening? Am I storing old values in inside the variables even after resetting the form and submitting a new one successfully? if so how can I truncate old assignments?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables should be defined locally to the `$("#submit_btn").click(function (e) {` function. You defined them in the `$(document).ready()` function, so they keep their values across each run of the inner function.

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/52VtD/1241/)

Comment: file_name, file_area, file_type should probably not be local to the validator function.  You'll probably want them in other parts of the code.

Comment: Perhaps. The one that really matters is `proceed`, it's only relevant to validation.

Comment: I might be wrong actually.  It might be that if someone is trying to change the values and fails that we don't want the old ones...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code with one line:

```
proceed = true;
```

Inside your submit function to re-initialize the variable that you use to trigger the submission.

Here's the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/RyZL4/).